# Finding a file in a Phoenix app script (Rails.root)

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Is there something similar to `Rails.root` for Phoenix.  Lets say I'd like to work with a configuration file in a Phoenix app.  What is the convention for finding the file and path for use in a script?

Comment: Sorry meant for this to be a comment http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.0/elixir/Path.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In case of Elixir this is not that easy as with Ruby, because your application is compiled - the compiled code resides in a different place than the source code.

The traditional place to put any additional resources for an Elixir/Erlang application is the `priv` directory alongside `lib`. Mix knows how to handle it, and expose it for the compiled code. 
You can access it at runtime either with `:code.priv_dir(my_app)` or with `Application.app_dir(my_app, "priv")`.

Comment: How can I find the root path at compile-time?